# Display 5 images in grid view magento category view page

Tags: xml, magento, product

I am trying to display 5 products on category page

```
app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
```

I am trying it on list.phtml, from other reference I have also tried

`<?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount();?>` to `<?php $_columnCount = 5 ;?>` but this does not work

Comment: what is your page layout ?2 columns or 1 columns ?

Comment: 1) "This does not work" is not an appropriate description of any problem. 2) Why `$this->5` instead of just `5`?

Comment: @KeyurShah page layout is 2columns-left

Comment: Do you want to display it for specific category page or all category pages ?

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy on all pages, its common for all

Comment: @Rhymoid its `<?php $_columnCount = 5 ;?>` sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

Try below code to display 5 product per row on your product listing page:

```
<catalog_category_default>
<reference name="product_list">
<action method="setColumnCount"><count>5</count></action>
</reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```